# Выбор языка для задачи

Tags: любой-язык

Мне необходимо написать программу для расчета движения заряженных частиц в электромагнитном поле. Функционал довольно простой - необходимо численным методом решить систему уравнений движения и полученный набор точек отобразить на трехмерном графике. Кол-во точек в траектории ~ 10^5. Какой язык лучше всего подходит для реализации данной программы? Любой из предложенных придется изучать с нуля, поэтому предпочтений нет. Буду благодарен за советы.

Answer (score 4):

10^5 — это совсем не много с точки зрения вычислений, поэтому я бы посоветовал брать язык, в котором удобнее общаться с графикой. Это либо C#/WPF, либо C++/Qt.

Из преимуществ WPF, там есть встроенные классы для работы с трёхмерными объектами. Ну или можно ими не пользоваться, а спроектировать нужные точки на плоскость экрана вручную (делов-то, домножить на матрицу 3х2). Ну и вам придётся как-то кластеризовать точки и выводить их не все сразу, т.к. 10^5 графических объектов система может и не потянуть. (Да вы и не разглядите такую детализацию на экране.)

Скорость числомолотилки не должна отличаться существенно.

В качестве извращённого варианта *можно* написать числомолотилку на чистом C или Fortran, и визуализировать результаты при помощи программы на более высокоуровневом языке. Но для этого вам придётся учить *два* языка, так что не советую.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробный ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста!